# como arreglar el comandos ctrl + z, etc en la terminal ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

tengo un problema con ubuntu 20.04 lts que no me deja utilizar control + a / z / c / x, etc. solo control + V. entonces si estoy escribiendo en la terminal y hago un error, no me deja volver atras. he buscado en todos lados pero no hay encuentro la solucion.

Comment: ¿Te funciona `Ctrl` + `V`? Normalmente la terminal de Ubuntu utiliza  `Ctrl` + `Shift` +`V`. Generalmente para los equivalentes en windows  `Ctrl` + `C` ó `Ctrl` + `V` se les agrega la tecla `Shift` ¿A que te refieres con volver atrás? Si te refieres a deshacer un comando que ejecutaste no puedes hacerlo. Si te refieres a que te muestre el último comando solo toca la flecha de arriba.

Comment: me funciona ctrl + V, pero ctrl + shift + V no me funciona. volver atras me refiero a ctrl + Z.  y por ejemplo, si me equivoco al escribir una linea y presiono enter, no me deja salir de ahi y tengo que cerrar y volver a abrir la ventana

Comment: Qué raro.¿No sales con `Ctrl` + `C`?

Comment: cuando preciono Ctrl + C. solo escribe  "^C"

Comment: En terminal no existe el Control + Z como creo que lo estas interpretando tu.  No es como en el modo gráfico, no hay un "deshacer".  E imagino que sucede lo mismo con las otras combinaciones de teclado que estas intentando usar como si eso fuera un entorno gráfico.  Para ir atras solo puedes borrar lo que has escrito y poca cosa mas, es la gracia del terminal :-D

Comment: ¿Podríás adjuntar una descripción  más detallada en tu pregunta? Por ejemplo con que comando suceden esas cosas. A partir de cuando comenzó. Y una captura ejemplo en donde sucede lo que describes. Eso ayudaría bastante a decantar el problema. Se que suena básico, ¿pero probaste mínimo reiniciando?

Comment: si me equivoque con el ctrl + Z, pero reinicie la computadora y ya esta funcionando bien. ya no se esta colgando la app. y me muestra los errores cuando escribo algo mal. gracias :)

Comment: Seguramente con tanta combinación de teclas que has probado lo habias dejado en modo raro, y quizas cerrando el terminal y volviendo a abrir otro ya lo tenias bien de nuevo, sin necesidad de reiniciar la computadora.